# Hook into pickle to obtain pre-binary representation?

Tags: python, pickle, dill

If I understand correctly, `pickle` converts the state of an object into something like a `dict` including the class of the object, and then writes that data to a binary file. Obtaining the state of an object is done via a [complex interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances), in the simplest case accessing the object's `__dict__` but possibly involving user-defined methods like `__getstate__`, `__setstate__`, etc. . When a pickle file is loaded, the binary data is read into a `dict`-like representation, and these converted back into objects.

**My question:** Is it possible to hook into `pickle` at the point after obtaining the object state but before writing the binary data, and the same in the other direction (after reading binary data but before restoring objects)?

Background: I'm thinking of implementing something similar to `jsonpickle` and `hickle`, i.e. having the same interface of `dump` and `load`, but using another file format to store data (here: JSON & HDF5). If possible, I would like to avoid reproducing the lengths `pickle` goes to in accessing and restoring object states but reuse that part, and only create a new "backend".

A solution using `dill` would be just as good.

Answer (score 0):

If you `dumps` an object, and look at the module `pickle.py`: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/pickle.py#L107, you'll see that `pickle` converts an object to a series of opcodes (and recursively stored data).  This is what is basically what is written to disk when you use `dump`.  I authored the part of `hickle` that stores arbitrary objects -- by first using `dill.dumps` to generate a string of optcodes and data, then using HDF to store the string. If you turn on tracing in `dill`, you can see how the opcodes and data are stored in the string.

```
>>> x = dict(a=[1,2,3], b=set((4,5,6)))
>>> import dill
>>> dill.detect.trace(True)
>>> dill.dumps(x)
D2: <dict object at 0x11023c870>
T1: <class 'set'>
F2: <function _load_type at 0x11070f2f0>
# F2
# T1
# D2
b'\x80\x03}q\x00(X\x01\x00\x00\x00aq\x01]q\x02(K\x01K\x02K\x03eX\x01\x00\x00\x00bq\x03cdill._dill\n_load_type\nq\x04X\x03\x00\x00\x00setq\x05\x85q\x06Rq\x07]q\x08(K\x04K\x05K\x06e\x85q\tRq\nu.'
```

It creates a dict, which stores a list of ints (no special function needed), then stores a special function (`load_type`) to help reconstitute the set, and finally stores the set of ints. Optcodes at the beginning signify the version and protocol.

So, yes, you can access the state (in serialized form) before it is dumped to file.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough: I wrote "before writing the binary data", but I actually meant "before converting into an opcode sequence". After some poking around, I imagine something similar to what `__reduce__` returns, except that that still contains function and class objects that don't have an obvious storage form.